# Android background restricted

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal, android-background

For using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) or any push notification like OneSignal, **the app should be running in the background**. but some custom ROM blocks all apps except some trusted apps like Facebook, WhatsApp, etc. For other apps we need to ask for user permission to enable the app to autostart in the background.

How can we check the app background restriction with any (lollipop+) Operating systems?
I've checked `isBackgroundRestricted()` and it requires `Android P` to execute

I'm trying to push notification and for that we need the app to be running in the background, to enable the settings I'm using [AutoStarter](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter) library.

But my problem is, this library just open the settings to enable the app to autostart, before that I want to check whether this app has enabled this setting or not

So how can we check the app is enabled `APP AUTOSTART` option or not?

My question is not about enabling the settings, it is about checking the status of the setting.